# How to loop over several rows multiplicating with a constant number in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a problem coding the following task:

| gene | constant value | Value A | Value B | Value C | Value D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 0.5224 | 123 | 456 | 789 | 123 |
| EFGH | 0.556 | 254 | 267 | 2334 | 12334 |
| IJKL | 0.7226 | 23423 | 56345 | 67867 | 17534 |
| MNOP | 0.0001 | 2423 | 143 | 1554 | 1344 |

Given this table I want to multiply every value with the constant value of the row, so in the end the code should calculate this:

| gene | constant value | Value A | Value B | Value C | Value D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABCD | 0.5224 | 123 * 0.5224 | 456 * 0.5224 | 789 * 0.5224 | 123 * 0.5224 |
| EFGH | 0.556 | 254 * 0.556 | 267 * 0.556 | 2334 * 0.556 | 12334 * 0.556 |
| IJKL | 0.7226 | 23423 * 0.7226 | 56345 * 0.7226 | 67867 * 0.7226 | 17534 * 0.7226 |
| MNOP | 0.0001 | 2423 * 0.0001 | 143 * 0.0001 | 1554 * 0.0001 | 1344 * 0.0001 |

Can anyone help how to implement this in R programming language?

Kind regards,
Hashriama

Comment: You can simply do `df[-c(1:2)] <- df[-c(1:2)] * df$constant_value`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another possible solution, based on base R:

(I have just noticed that @Sotos had, in a comment, suggested something very similar; therefore, I am going to remove my answer.)

```r
df[-(1:2)] <-  df$constant.value * df[-(1:2)]
df

#>   gene constant.value    Value.A    Value.B    Value.C    Value.D
#> 1 ABCD         0.5224    64.2552   238.2144   412.1736    64.2552
#> 2 EFGH         0.5560   141.2240   148.4520  1297.7040  6857.7040
#> 3 IJKL         0.7226 16925.4598 40714.8970 49040.6942 12670.0684
#> 4 MNOP         0.0001     0.2423     0.0143     0.1554     0.1344
```

Comment: Nooooo...leave it. It's fine :)

Comment: Thanks, @Sotos! I just did not want to usurp your credits, although I reached the same solution independently.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dplyr` package, you can use the `across()` helper function to apply the same operation across multiple columns that `starts_with` "Value".

```
library(dplyr)

# dplyr approach
df %>% mutate(across(starts_with("Value"), ~.x * `constant value`))

# or similarly in base R
df[, grepl("Value", colnames(df))] <- df[, grepl("Value", colnames(df))] * df$`constant value`

  gene constant value    Value A    Value B    Value C    Value D
1 ABCD         0.5224    64.2552   238.2144   412.1736    64.2552
2 EFGH         0.5560   141.2240   148.4520  1297.7040  6857.7040
3 IJKL         0.7226 16925.4598 40714.8970 49040.6942 12670.0684
4 MNOP         0.0001     0.2423     0.0143     0.1554     0.1344
```

#### Input data

```
df <- read.table(header = T, sep = "\t", check.names = F, text = "
gene    constant value  Value A Value B Value C Value D
ABCD    0.5224  123 456 789 123
EFGH    0.556   254 267 2334    12334
IJKL    0.7226  23423   56345   67867   17534
MNOP    0.0001  2423    143 1554    1344")
```